# Importing data from mysql to mongodb using springboot

Tags: mysql, mongodb, spring-boot

I have data stored in mysql database, and i want to import them into mongodb using springboot. Is there any way we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use spring-jpa (or even spring JdbcTemplate) with MySQL jdbc jar to pull the data and spring MongoTemplate to write.

As you are not running spring boot as a server you can turn it off with:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Start the processing with:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup(
    // do some reading and writing
}
```